# Is it shirk to have a fictional OC who’s a god?

Tags: shirk

I have a fictional OC who’s a god but I do not worship them nor do I believe in them. I only write fictional stories about my OC, I do not share those stories and only write them for entertainment. Have I committed shirk by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

Allahﷻ bless you
It is forbidden to write about a character who you imagine in your mind is a god, and stop thinking like that.